# place image on page bottom-right (dynamic)

Tags: layout, css

I want to place image on the page which stays on the page bottom-right (floats) and I want to place the image even when the browser window re size..

How can I make this possible??

Thanks in advance... `:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: jQuery UI plug-in or Ajax Toolkit?

Comment: is there any way using jquery ui???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<div style="position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0; z-index: 999">
    <img src="/src/to/image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note: IE6 doesn't support fixed positioning.

Comment: I just ignore IE6, I am not going to pollute my code just to support a dying thing :-) I see your point very clearly but I made a decision to just say FU IE6

Comment: +1 But, if I could give +2 I would have done so, 1 for the right answer and 1 for the "FU IE6" :)

Comment: Haha. I totally agree, but it still needed to be said because, while you may be able to ignore it, the OP may not. And @Bazzz you can up-vote his comment.